# Pug block definition in include called twice

Tags: pug

I wrote a component as a mixin which I include then call, as suggested [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/798)

The component has some HTML **and** some JS in it.

I put all the JS in a `js` block at it called at the bottom of the layout, *after* all libraries.

My issue is that the block definition gets actually printed during include, which is not a behavior I'd expect.

- Can I prevent the block from being printed at first?
- Or can I get around the whole situation?

The Code:

content.pug:

```
body
  include /mixins/my-mixin
  +myMixin('my-module-public')
  script(src='/assets/js/libs/jquery.js')
  block js
```

/mixins/my-mixin.pug:

```
mixin myMixin(id)
  .my-module(id=id)
    p Hey you

block js
  script(type='text/javascript').
    jQuery('.my-module').myModule();
```

The result:

```
<body>
  <script>jQuery('.my-module').myModule();</script>
  <div id="my-module-public" class="my-module"><p>Hey you</p></div>
  <script src="/assets/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>jQuery('.my-module').myModule();</script>
</body>
```

The issue comes from the first `<script>` tag that is not expected.

Thanks

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html states: "__Includes allow you to insert the contents of one Pug file into another__."

Comment: And? You mean a `block` block is not pug content? How can I know about it?

Comment: I have the same issue. It would help to be able to define blocks inside of includes. Helps me from repeating something a hundred times elsewhere.